# How to specify what version of nginx Google App Engine uses?

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to specify which version of nginx is used by Google App Engine in a flexible environment?

The [app.yaml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/reference/app-yaml) doesn't specify it.

Is it just not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the version of nginx if you use "Custom Runtimes".

Here is the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) and a [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-custom-runtimes-samples/tree/master/nginx) for deploying an app in the flexible environment using custom runtimes.

You specify the version of nginx in the Dockerfile like this: `FROM nginx:<version>` for example I changed it to `FROM nginx:1.14.2`.